# pyinstaller does not show images and icon

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I read many tutorials on how to include image and icons by modifying the spec file though I couldn't succeed.I wrote a program which I want to make executable using pyinstaller and run it on other computers. pyinstaller doesnot include image and icon files on the main .exe file. When I run the compiled .exe file on my own pc it works just fine but when I try to run the same file on other computer, it throws an error.. Please suggest me how do I do it, this is driving off my brain..
Thanks in advance..
below is my .spec file code and my python script(partial)

.spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['English-Nepali.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Dict'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='English-Nepali.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=None,
               upx=True,
               name='English-Nepali')
```

part of the program where image and icon is used, both ico and jpg files are present in the directory:

```
class Demo2:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.geometry("640x250+200+200")
        master.resizable(False,False)
        self.master.title('About')
        self.img = Image.open(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Dict\rotunda.jpg")
        self.tetras = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)

def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    ex = Example(root)
    root.iconbitmap(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Dict\1.ico")
    root.resizable(False,False)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I suggest you to add error messsage.

Comment: put the .ico & .jpg files in the folder that pyinstaller creates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the `.ico` & `.jpg` files in the folder that `pyinstaller` created.

Comment: At the build folder?