# Executable Created With Pyinstaller Couldn't Open Image

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

I've written a program using the Pygame module and am trying to use it to create an `.exe` which I can share with friends. In my Python scripts directory I have a folder which contains the `.py` file and a folder called `images` which contains the images used in the program. The program works just fine as a `.py`, but as soon as I convert it to an `.exe` via pyinstaller It fails to work.

Below is a minimum functional example:

```
import os
import pygame

def load_image(name):
    fullname = os.path.join("images", name)
    image = pygame.image.load(fullname)
    return image

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
image = load_image("image.bmp")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    screen.blit(image,(0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

I compile this using `pyinstaller --onefile example.py`.
I then execute from the command and receive the following error:

```
Traceback <most recent call last>:
    File "<string>", line 11 in <module>
    File "<string>", line 6 in load_image
pygame.error: Couldn't open images\image.bmp
example returned -1
```

I'm assuming this has something to do with local vs. global paths but no matter how much I fiddle I can't seem to get it up and running.

What do I need to change to be able to open the image file when using pyinstaller?

Comment: Have you tried sending the whole path?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyinstaller and --onefile: How to include an image in the exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836104/pyinstaller-and-onefile-how-to-include-an-image-in-the-exe-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) about the data files with something like:

```
pyinstaller --add-data 'images/image.bmp:.' --onefile example.py
```

From the ([DOCS](http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html?highlight=data#adding-data-files))

Comment: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search