# Compile Python project without users having access to your files

Tags: python, installation, pyinstaller

so I am attempting to compile a few files into an executable using PyInstaller. The problem I'm running into is that my main file, login.py is dependent on other files. My question is, is it possible to compile all the files into one executable so that the user can just receive that one executable without them having access to the source code?

[image: explanation]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bundling data files with PyInstaller (--onefile)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile)

Comment: @recessive I did use the —onefile command

Comment: try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836104/pyinstaller-and-onefile-how-to-include-an-image-in-the-exe-file . Otherwise, if you're really desperate, you can use something like PIL to get the exact pixel data of the images, store them as a list in your python file, then recreate them on the fly. Same goes for audio, but use scipy.