# How to distribute a a python script to users without them having to install python

Tags: python, build, compilation, software-distribution

I want to be able to compile my python script & associated files (a .py file with a few sounds and images + a .json save file) in a way that users can just download and play.

I've already tried pyinstaller but it doesn't attach all my images and sound files and when the executable is run it just errors because it can't find the files it needs.

the program will close out here:

```py
icon = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(sys.path[0], "images\icon.png"))
```

it would be great if the exe could just be sent out to people and run when needed instead of them needing to install python and my program's dependencies.

Comment: I think the answer is here：
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836104/pyinstaller-and-onefile-how-to-include-an-image-in-the-exe-file

Comment: But I'll also have the JSON file which will change - it acts as a save file. Can that be included too?