# Images in Python exe file

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have created an app in which i am using png images as buttons. I included those images in the exe files as data when i was creating the exe file through pyinstaller, but those images are not shown in the exe file. I manually copied and pasted those images in the folder where the exe file is but still those images are not shown. what could go wrong any idea ? please

Comment: You should post a minimal, reproducible example of your code here.

Comment: This thread might help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836104/pyinstaller-and-onefile-how-to-include-an-image-in-the-exe-file

Comment: thousend things can go wrong!