# How do I add an image into a onefile pyinstaller executable?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm having trouble with my pyinstaller executable, when I launch it I get this error:

[image]

The problem is due to the exe not being able to find an image file 'icon.ico' because pyinstaller didn't package the file inside the executable file. What I'm asking is how I would package the icon inside the EXE file and what the directory for that icon file would be after it has been packaged. The image file is being used as an icon for a Tkinter GUI.

This is the code for the Tkinter app:

```
app = Tk()
app.title('MagnetMagnet - RARBG Scraper')
app.iconbitmap(r'icon.ico')
app.geometry('500x225')

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is save the `Bytes` of the Image,and when open it,Save the picture in your PC,and use `app.iconbitmap(r'icon.ico')`.

Firstly,use `open` to get the Image Bytes:

```
with open('icon.ico','rb') as f:
    ImageBytes = f.read()
print(ImageBytes)
# b'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Then your all code should be:

```
ImageBytes = b'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
with open('icon.ico','wb') as f:
    f.write(ImageBytes)
app = Tk()
app.title('MagnetMagnet - RARBG Scraper')
app.iconbitmap(r'icon.ico')
app.geometry('500x225')
app.mainloop()
```

When you open this exe file,it will generate a new `ico` Image,you can delete it.And it will generate a new one again next time when you open it.

Comment: This is a really easy method! Thanks!
I was scratching my head trying to understand whatever this man did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836104/pyinstaller-and-onefile-how-to-include-an-image-in-the-exe-file

But you swooped in and saved me a lot of time
Thank you kind stranger

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have to give the icon in the python file.
instead type `pyinstaller -i iconfile pythonfile` in your terminal(Windows)

Comment: I ran `pyinstaller -i icon.ico MagnetMagnet.py` as you suggested, problem still persists. The app would only work if I moved the icon file into the executable's directory.

Comment: try  ```pyinstaller -F -i icon.ico MangetMagnet.py ```

Comment: Still the same issue, I have to move the icon file for it to work.