# Python pyinstaller executable problem with image

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, python-3.7, py2exe

I am converting the Python file to exe, but the images (icon, background etc.) in the project are not included in exe. How can I fix this?
**(I would also like to mention that I have included the pictures in the project using PixMap in PyQT. If exe and pictures are in the same folder, it works properly but does not work in different locations.)**

Comment: See this question regarding embeding resources in compilations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836104/pyinstaller-and-onefile-how-to-include-an-image-in-the-exe-file