# Why images and icons don't load when converting .py to .exe with pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to convert a Python program to exe using pyinstaller, the program has 1 icon and 1 png picture, so when I convert it with pyinstaller, everything works perfectly except the pictures are not loading, it gives me this error: `Failed to obtain/convert traceback!`, but when I copy-paste the two pics in the same folder as the exe, it loads!, however, I just want to avoid that, is it possible to package it all including pictures? Note: I tried using --onefile and --windowed as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyinstaller and --onefile: How to include an image in the exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836104/pyinstaller-and-onefile-how-to-include-an-image-in-the-exe-file)

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't understand what he was doing