# Pyinstaller executable saves files to temp folder

Tags: python, path, pyinstaller

I am having a problem where I can't save files in the executable directory. Specifically

it saves it to `C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI102682\screenie.png`

**Pyinstaller command:** `pyinstaller --onefile main.py`

**code:**

```
import pyautogui
import os

__dir__ = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) + '\\'

print("Taking screenshot...")

pyautogui.screenshot().save(__dir__ + "screenie.png")
print(f"Saved to: {__dir__}screenie.png\nPress enter to open the file.")
input()
os.system(__dir__ + "screenie.png")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42615559/15649230) thread shows the correct way to get the executable path.

there are a few paths you should know.

1. `sys.executable` gets you the location of `python.exe` during development, but it gets you the path of your `.exe` after you make one.
2. `sys._MEIPASS` which contains the path to the temporary directory used by pyinstaller where your `.pyd` and `.dll` are extracted, it also houses any data you put using `--add-data`. (which is what you are getting)، as it's where pyinstaller expects your libraries to be.

as pyinstaller sets `sys.frozen=True`, you can use that to know what to used at runtime.

```py
import sys, os

def get_script_folder():
    # path of main .py or .exe when converted with pyinstaller
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        script_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
    else:
        script_path = os.path.dirname(
            os.path.abspath(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__)
        )
    return script_path

def get_data_folder():
    # path of your data in same folder of main .py or added using --add-data
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        data_folder_path = sys._MEIPASS
    else:
        data_folder_path = os.path.dirname(
            os.path.abspath(sys.modules['__main__'].__file__)
        )
    return data_folder_path
```

if you want the folder of your main script your just call `get_script_folder()`, but if you want the folder to your "data" (such as embedded images, etc) you should use `get_data_folder()`.

Comment: This does not work for one-file executables as one comment in the linked thread pointed out. The variable `sys._MEIPASS` holds the path to the temp directory. It recommends to use `sys.executable` for one-file executables which in my test worked: `os.path.dirname(sys.executable)`

Comment: @cweigel you are correct, i wonder why no-one found that out in 2 years, it even had 3 upvotes, anyway, the answer is updated and it's now correct and explains the problem in detail.

Comment: This one might help further with examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72060275/10789707

Answer (score 0):

Use terminal

```html
pyinstaller --specpath DIR main.py
```

file main.exe in dist\main\main.exe
Run file main.exe then  files save in the executable directory in your projcet