# How can I get a PyInstaller executable to create a file in the same directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, executable

***I found the answer***
So it looks like PyInstaller actually runs in a temp directory, not your own, which explains my issue. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405069/pyinstaller-executable-saves-files-to-temp-folder) is an explanation for that. I guess I will keep this up incase people in the future have problems.

---

***Original question***

I am trying to use PyInstaller to create an executable of a simple python script called `test.py` that just creates a text file and adds numbers to it, as a test of PyInstaller. This file works correctly when run normally.

```
from os.path import dirname, abspath

def main():
    txtfile = dirname(abspath(__file__)) + '/text.txt'
    with open(txtfile, 'w') as f:
        for num in range(101):
            f.write(str(num) + '\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print('script executed')
```

When I use:
`pyinstaller test.py --onefile` in the same directory as `test.py` it successfully creates the `dist` file with the binary file `test` inside of it.

when I `cd dist` and do `./test` to execute the file inside `dist` it successfully prints out `main called` and `script executed` but it doesn't actually create the file. So, main is being called and the script is being executed, but the file isn't created at all, and I am quite confused about what I'm doing wrong..I must be getting file paths messed up? But I have specified the exact full path with os.path, so it doesn't make sense to me.

The system exit code is 0, and there are no errors raised when I call `./test`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyinstaller executable saves files to temp folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405069/pyinstaller-executable-saves-files-to-temp-folder)

Comment: When you find the answer to your question in another stack overflow post, that is a good indication that your question is a duplicate and should probably be removed

Comment: There is a subtle difference in my post and their post. To find that post, they would have to know that it does save it to a temp file. But people don't know that, which this post would lead them to that info.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70405069/pyinstaller-executable-saves-files-to-temp-folder) that shows that PyInstaller will save to a temp file. I created this script below to check if the script is being executed directly or via PyInstaller.

```
import os
import sys

def create_file(path):
    with open(path + '/test.txt', 'w') as f:
        for num in range(101):
            f.write(str(num) + '\n')

def check_using_pyinstaller():
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
        return application_path
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def main():
    path = check_using_pyinstaller()
    os.chdir(path)
    create_file(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```