# How to convert python file to exe with images and with no console?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I'm trying to convert a python file to exe with images and with no console but I do not know the exact functions to use, please help.

I tried doing

pyinstaller main.py --add-data "image.png" --noconsole

but didn't work

Comment: What didn't work? Is it a project or just a single file? Update your question with these details.

Comment: I use something called AutoPyExe or something similar. https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/  <-- thats the link. Just convert the main script into an exe and nothing else in the file. Only the script thats supposed to run when you click run should be converted.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When I use pyinstaller, I [edit the spec file to add images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836104/pyinstaller-and-onefile-how-to-include-an-image-in-the-exe-file)