# pyinstaller doesn't change python executable window icon

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to change the default python icon in my executable using pyinstaller. I'm trying this on Windows 10 and the GUI framework is pyqt5.

I have only managed to change the icon of the application (as seen in a file) but not the icons when you open the application (on the app's window).

These are the commands I used after a bit of online searching:

> pyinstaller SSL_Configurator.py
>
> pyinstaller --onefile -w --icon="favicon.ico"
> SSL_Configurator.py
>
> pyinstaller --onefile -w --icon="favicon.ico"
> --paths=<C:\Users\Haylee\Desktop\python>\Lib\site-packages SSL_Configurator.py

What else should I include in order to get the icon to be displayed on the window as well?

thanks

Comment: pyinstaller doesn't control this.  Look in the documentation for whatever GUI you are using

Comment: When I run the application in VS Code, the icon appears on the window, so it might be a Windows 10 thing. I use this: self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("favicon.ico"))

Comment: The problem is most likely that you are not compiling the favicon with your executable

Comment: Oh I see. After your comment I googled and found this [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72060275/17016288) which solved my problem.

Comment: Yes, it's the same link I posted. thanks

Comment: I know... that was me voting to close your question because it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Alexander's comment, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72060275/17016288) that explains how to fix this. Basicaly you need to compile the image with the code.

new pyinstaller command would look like this (after following the answer linked):

> pyinstaller --onefile -w --add-data "favicon.ico;." --icon="favicon.ico"
> --paths=<C:\Users\Haylee\Desktop\python>\Lib\site-packages SSL_Configurator.py