# How to include png files in pyinstaller packaging?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pyside6

I'm making a PySdie6 web browser. There are buttons like back, forward, refresh etc. in my web browser.

When I package this using PyInstaller, (`pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --name "Name" --icon "Path" browser.py`) and run the .exe file, the icons are not visible in my final .exe file. How could I fix this?

Since this is a project I'm eager to distribute, I'd like a method that preserves the files if I distribute the .exe file to a customer, say.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyinstaller and --onefile: How to include an image in the exe file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31836104/pyinstaller-and-onefile-how-to-include-an-image-in-the-exe-file)

Comment: @MarceloPaco, Not quite. I believe that simply adds a path to the QIcon method. While this may help me see the icons on my PC, the other users will need to make a folder in the same exact path to see the icons, which isn't feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a work around you can add it manually to the spec file if it's not there.
See [here](https://shanetully.com/2013/08/cross-platform-deployment-of-python-applications-with-pyinstaller/) as a reference.